# Is it good to present multiple POVs in a single answer?

Tags: discussion, pov, answers

It seems the community considers it [unreasonable to *ask* for multiple POVs](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46/is-it-reasonable-to-ask-for-both-sides-of-an-argument) (POV means point of view). What does the community say about *answering* with multiple POVs? I personally see many benefits and few downsides, but I'd like to know if others consider this appropriate.

As an example: [my answer to *To what extent does the Law of Moses still apply?*](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/456/to-what-extent-does-the-law-of-moses-still-apply/494#494)

Comment: Related: [Inquiring perspectives on one matter from throughout all of the Christianity spectrum](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/870/21576)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that it is unfair for a question to demand multiple POV answers, that doesn't make multiple POV answers a bad thing in themselves. In many cases I think answering with multiple POVs is not only acceptable but beneficial. If you have studied a topic and are qualified to make a statement about how other people view something, adding that as balance to an answer is a good thing.

On the other hand, the inclusion of multiple POVs should not be the only measure of a good answer. Some questions will solicit answers from multiple quarters and it is OK to have more than one good answer to a question with each presenting a single view.

**Whether answering from a single or multiple point of view, clearly identifying the espoused view is critical to keep the votes from being a popularity content**. If I see an answer that says "X" and I think "X" does not represent Christianity I would down-vote it. If I saw an answer that says "Such and such a group believes X" I might upvote it as a good answer even if I think such and such a group isn't even Christian.

Answer (score 5):

One of the things specifically stated on the whole StackExchange StackOverflow introduction is that **synthesised answers are good**. It is unreasonable to expect that every answer encompasses all points of view. However it is a good principle that **answers should identify their viewpoint** and that **multiple viewpoint answers should be voted up** compared with single viewpoint answers. In fact I believe this is **essential** if we don't want to make every answer a vote war.

A good corollary of this is that **people should be prepared to take multiple answers from different viewpoints and compile a single answer from them**. I would say we need people to devote themselves specifically to that task.