# Questions of "What is your interpretation of X passage"

Tags: discussion

For other SE sites, I think personal interpretations of specific scripture is off-topic as too subjective.

Are question asking specifically for 'how does you interpret ... passage' on topic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a continuation of the discussion that started on [Personal viewpoints](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201/personal-viewpoints) in regard to answers that only claim to speak for a personal viewpoint. If there is not a defined point of reference that an answer can be judged on, it becomes a voting contest between viewpoints rather than on the quality of information in answers.

Questions that specifically ask for personal viewpoints will only make this problem worse, I say no, in general they should be off topic.

Instead let's encourage questions that have a clearly defined scope and thus can be answered more or less "correctly".

Comment: oh sorry, didn't see that Personal viewpoints thread. I think that is in essence what I was asking.

Comment: except i guess mine was about questions, not answers. So i'll keep it for people to vote on.

Answer (score -4):

My thought is they can be on-topic as 'poll' questions for giving different viewpoints, but possibly be marked as community wiki.

Comment: Poll questions are not a good fit for SE sites in the first place.

Comment: @Caleb: Correct... and you can't make them a better fit by marking them Community Wiki: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

Comment: @Robert Thanks for that link. I probably should read the blogs more often.